# Need a formula that will pull the specific value that matches a unique code from a set of data and produce another table of that specific data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyRAG.png)

I need a formula that can pick out the unique codes seen in the second table labelled x and the data set 2 from the source table, matching up the correct values.

tried using functions like find, match, index and google yet no result.

Comment: Index & Match will certainly work. Also Vlookup, Xlookup, Filter

Answer (score 1):

Simple `VLOOKUP` will work: [vlookup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

```
=VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$D$11,3,FALSE)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be dynamic using `VLOOKUP()` with `MATCH()`

```
=VLOOKUP($G2,$A$2:$D$17,MATCH(H$1,$A$1:$D$1,0),0)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBQcR.png)

---

This can be dynamic using `XLOOKUP()` with `FILTER()`

```
=XLOOKUP($G2,$A$2:$A$17,FILTER($B$2:$D$17,H$1=$B$1:$D$1))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyH1H.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxdFw.gif)